# Access scope from ng-template

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-dialog

Using AngularJS, I want to access scope variable from inside a `<script type="text/ng-template"`.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="firstDialogId">
    <div class="ngdialog-message" align="center" id="download">
        <h4 ng-show=isFrench>Télécharger la cartographie</h4>
        <h4 ng-show=isEnglish>Download cartography</h4>
        <a href="../downloads/PDF/{{currentLanguage}}/{{currentCartography}}.pdf" download>
            <img  src="../style/images/pdf-icon.png" alt="Download PDF" width="30%" height="30%">
        </a>   
        <a href="../downloads/VSD/{{currentCartography}}.vsd" download>
            <img border="0" src="../style/images/vsd-icon.png" alt="Download VSD" width="30%" height="30%">
        </a>   
        <a href="../downloads/PNG/{{currentLanguage}}/{{currentCartography}}.png" download>
            <img border="0" src="../style/images/PNG-icon.png" alt="Download PNG" width="30%" height="30%">
        </a>   

         <div class="ngdialog-buttons">
             <button type="button" class="ngdialog-button ngdialog-button-primary" ng-click="closeThisDialog('button')">Close</button>
         </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

`isFrench` and `isEnglish` are 2 booleans from my controller.

Same for `currentCartography` and `currentLanguage`, they are strings from my controller.

I also tried with getter inside and outside of the controller, same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For those falling into the same issue :

Using ngDialog, we need to precise we want to use the scope.
In my case, I added the dialog open functions in my controller, I needed to edit the one I'm using in order to add the `scope: $scope,` line as follows :

```
$scope.openPlainCustomWidth = function () {
    $rootScope.theme = 'ngdialog-theme-plain custom-width';
    ngDialog.open({
        template: 'firstDialogId',
        controller: 'InsideCtrl',
        className: 'ngdialog-theme-plain custom-width',
        scope: $scope, // this line wasn't here before
        closeByDocument: false
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

three things you can try

1. use `ng-href` instead of `href`
2. for ng-show remove double curly `{{`
3. if above two doesnt work use $parent (only if you are not using controller-as)

Comment: My bad for the double curly, I just forgot.
I corrected it and chenged href to ng-href, but it didnt change anything.

How do I use $parent ? Do you have any link/example ?

Comment: `$parent.isFrench`, isFrench is on parent scope, if does not work just try `<pre>{{$parent | json}}</pre>`, or basically open batrange and check the scopes parent child relationshio

Comment: `<h4 ng-show=$parent.isFrench>...</h4>` is not working.
`<h4 ng-show="<pre>{{$parent.isFrench | json}}</pre>">...</h4>` is always true, regardless the value of isFrench
Also, since i wasnt sure how to use it, I also tried `<h4 ng-show="<pre>{{$parent | json}}.isFrench</pre>">...</h4>` but same, always true.

Comment: no no.. u r getting it wrong.. `ng-show="$parent.isFrench"` see the quotes around it... and the `<pre>` is not value of ng-show.. it is used to see the data...

Comment: `<h4 ng-show="$parent.isFrench">...</h4>` with or without quotes is always false.

Comment: then its upto you to debug it further using batrang

Comment: I found my problem, it was specific to ngDialog that I am using.
I don't know batarang but thanks, it looks usefull.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `ng-show` incorrectly, it doesn't use `{{}}` expressions.

Try: `ng-show="isFrench"`

Beyond that it isn't clear what you are asking

Comment: Yea I forgot to remove the double curly but this is still not working.
Well, I'm asking how to access my controller variabes, since I can't here.

Comment: what do you mean by `access controller variables`? Please show how you are using template and where in your code you have problems. Do you have an isolated scope in a directive using the template?

Comment: Well, I mean that my isFrench and isEngilsh are not working here. And they are variable from my controller. I just can't access them here.
I'm displaying them, and the value is correct.
And about the template I'm using ngDialog that I found online. Here is the git : https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog

Comment: because the `ngDialog` directive is using isolated scope. Are you passing anything to `ng-dialog-scope` ? Where are docs for directive?

Comment: I edited my last comment, to provide git instead of js file, everythinf we can found about this ngDialog is there : https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog

Comment: Not clear how you are using it. Suggest you create a demo that replicates your issue. Can pass either controller or scope to the `open()` method and I'm not sure how you have it configured

Comment: Thanks man, I found what I needed to change.
In my controller I needed to add `scope: $scope` in the concerned dialog open function to be able to use the $scope.